# Running sparkR file in linux

Tags: apache-spark

From java i am calling shellscript, through shellscript i am calling sparkR file (`test.R`) while  running `Test.R` i am getting below error:

> Error in read.df(sqlContext, source =
>   "com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource") :

1. `Test.R` contains below code

   ```
   .libPaths(c("/opt/app/workload/deployments/servers/R-3.4.2/lib",.libPaths())) 

   sw <- read.df(sqlContext, source = "com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource")
   ```
2. shellscript

   ```
   sparkR filename
   ```
3. java code

   ```
   public class TestShell 
   {
       public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
           String s=null;
           String[] cmdScript = new String[]{ "/bin/sh","/opt/app/workload/deployments/packages/POC/training.sh"}; 
           Process procScript = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdScript);
           BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new 
               InputStreamReader(procScript.getInputStream()));
           System.out.println("Here is the standard output of the command:\n");
           while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
               System.out.println(s);
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: I resolved this issue ....i am loading R lib instead of loading Spark lib....R lib is not having read.df method  ....

Comment: i have written spring boot application in STS and i have ran, it is running successful then i have created executable jar then i ran, it is throwing error , below is the my code

Comment: String nameClass="file:///C://Users/username/Desktop/Navneet/TFSJAR/"+name;
    String jarName="file:///C://Users/username/Desktop/TFS/IPInstallJAR.jar";
    URLClassLoader clsLoader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(new URL[] {new URL(nameClass),new URL(jarName)});
    GenModel genModel = (GenModel) clsLoader.loadClass(className).newInstance();
  and

Comment: and below error is throwing                    java.lang.ClassCastException: TFSInstallModel_2018_01_25 cannot be cast to hex.genmodel.GenModel